# Migration from ClearCase to local machine

Tags: perl, scripting, migration, clearcase

We are migrating from clearcase. But we want to grab everything form clearcase and archive locally for historical purpose. Is there any easy way to do or any kind of script (perl) which will migrate, zip and archive locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to dump vobs into an export file.

See "[Moving VOBs and relocating VOB data](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/vob-relo-mv.htm)"

```
cleartool reformatvob -dump /vobstore/avob.vbs
```

You can then tar gz the dumped vobstore.

You can move it anywhere else and reload it when you need it.

Comment: @knm it is best to formulate your questions here on Stack Overflow: that way other new users will benefit from them. In the meantime, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I am kinda new in ClearCase as well. but when you run this command it will format or remove right? In near future company wants to get rid of ClearCase. if someone wants to know what was  in CC, can't  go back and look, coz there won't be Clearcase. So, we want to capture all data (say vobs, projects, streams,baselines, binaries, metadata, changes etc historically) import and save locally. can you tell me easiest way please?

Comment: @knm same here: we are migrating all ClearCase vobs, but we are leaving a ClearCase server running for archive: we only migrate the last few baselines, and don't keep *all* the history. What is your target SCM (Source Control Management) tool?

Comment: this migration part is being done to the target but only baselines.now  they want to capture and keep all the info locally for historical purpose.

Comment: @knm then you need a dedicated tool to migrate to a repo you can maintain, like an SVN repo: see for instance http://www.clearvision-cm.com/scm-consulting/clearcase-subversion-migration/

Comment: thanks much. but simply i want to capture all data and archive locally. we have migrated the baselines already to other SCM tool and repo.

Comment: @knm then the reformatvob does that, but if you want to read it again, you would need another ClearCase to reload the vob.

Comment: Thanks. yeah CC gonna stay for a year or two, so we don't want to reformatvob. Again all info and real codes to be copied locally.

Comment: HI VonC, I am new here @stackoverflow.com "lets forgot about the future repo or SCM tool, for now if you want to grab everything locally, can i do cleartool reformatvob ? will that bring all (changes, version, activities,....etc) locally? i want to be sure coz i don't want to break ClearCase"

Comment: @knm yes, `reformatvob` is the tool you use to transfer a vob form one server to another (even with different OS), so yes, it brings everything.

Comment: i think the idea you have provided is only works if you want to go back to ClearCase or moving to another SCM tool. my point is we have migrated major baselines to different SCM tool already. we still have ClearCase. we want to capture all version, change, baseline, etc and zip it or put it in a flat file or so.is there any other idea?

Comment: @knm capturing *all* event is only stored, and exported, in the vob store through `reformatvob`. And those events wouldn't be put in a flat file anyway. What would be the use of such an archive with all those data?

Comment: yeah we want to archive all those data for historical purpose.I am not sure but doing reformatvob won't help or wont be human readable right?

Comment: @knm I confirm that archive wouldn't be readable without ClearCase.