# How to capture all information from ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I need some help on how to collect all information from ClearCase and tar or zip it, and store it in a provided space. we have migrated major baselines from ClearCase to different SCM tool .But we still have ClearCase. we want to capture all version, change, baseline, etc (basically capture everything but not the SCM tool itself) and zip it or put it in a flat file or so. this is just for historical purposes, so that tomorrow if someone wants to know what was in the ClearCase then they can see. so ,is there any idea?

Comment: I hope another ClearCase specialist will give you a different answer, but you might take this question to IBM support. Because on Stack Overflow, there are very few of us who answer ClearCase questions: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/topusers

Comment: I am sure you are the best resource here in stack overflow, is there anyway i can chat with you so i may clearly explain you.

Comment: sure (not just right now though). However, I would still recommend contacting IBM support for this. If there is a way, they would know it.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I would like to set up an appointment or time with you and discuss about my query. let me know what is the best time for you and I will manage mine accordingly. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @VonC is there any day or time that you will be available for to chat? can you provide me please ? I will have peace of mind.

Comment: Try and ping me on this comment section tomorrow afternoon (Paris time: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html?iso=20130914&p1=195)

Comment: Hi VonC I am really sorry I missed this opportutnity, but is there anyway we can meet sunday evening of your Paris time (about after 6 p.m.).As I live in the PST time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't exist (as far as I know) is in the [nature of ClearCase (compared to a revision-based VCS tools)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645424/6309).

It is a `file-based` VCS:

- You create a new version for each file you change (instead of a unique repository-wide revision)
- You create a label on each file you want to label (instead of a tag referring to a revision or a commit)
- You create a branch for each file modified in that branch (instead of a single directory for SVN, or branch for other VCS)
- ...

That means you wouldn't simply export revisions/labels/branches with ClearCase. You would export them *for each file*: it doesn't scale well and would take too much time and space.

Migrating major baselines is sensible course of action that I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/861554/6309) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502644/6309) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240088/6309).

But for the rest, I always put a ClearCase instance as a way to explore the *full* history/events in case in is needed, while the recent history is managed in the new VCS tool.

Storing that as a flat file you could read without ClearCase isn't, again as far as I know, available.
Hence my previous ["vobstore-reformatvob" proposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18525366/6309).